# Converting an object to multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a JSON file "icon.json" which contains:

```
[
    {
        "name": "sad",
        "url": "1.gif"
    },
    {
        "name": "smile",
        "url": "2.gif"
    },
    {
        "name": "smile2",
        "url": "3.gif"
    }
]
```

And  I load it with AJAX in my html file

```
var c1 = [];
var c2 = [];
function testget(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'icon.json',
        type: 'GET'
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
        // how to convert msg to array c1 and c2
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    testget();
});
```

Please tell me how to convert the object returned from the AJAX call to array c1 and c2 like this:

```
c1 = ["sad", "smile", "smile2"];
c2 = ["1.gif", "2.gif", "3.gif"];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with a simple loop:

```
.done(function(msg) {
    for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
        c1.push(msg[i].name);
        c2.push(msg[i].url);
    }
})
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rcsps1xa/)